# How to add same body class in multiple pages using their page id?

Tags: body-class

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );

function custom_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page( '38034' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'new-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Above code works fine to add a class in a page which id 38034. Now I want to add same class in multiple pages, how I can do that?

can I write `if ( is_page( '38034, 10883, 12031' ) ) {`

Note: I have no php knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you must **always return** the classes in your callback.

So move this part:

```
return $classes;
```

out of the `if` condition.

The `is_page()` does support multiple ID's when it's in an array.

This should work:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );

function custom_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page( [ 38034, 10883, 12031 ] ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'new-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```